# algorithm to create bounding rectangles for 2D points

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

The input is a series of point coordinates (x0,y0),(x1,y1) .... (xn,yn) (n is not very large, say ~ 1000). We need to create some rectangles as bounding box of these points. There's no need to find the global optimal solution. The only requirement is if the euclidean distance between two point is less than R, they should be in the same bounding rectangle. I've searched for sometime and it seems to be a clustering problem and K-means method might be a useful one. 
However, the input point coordinates didn't have specific pattern from time to time. So it maybe not possible to set a specific K in K-mean. I am wondering if there is any algorithm or method possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> The only requirement is if the euclidean distance between two point is less than R, they should be in the same bounding rectangle

This is the **definition** of single-linkage hierarchical clustering cut at a height of R.

Note that this may yield overlapping rectangles.

For much faster and highly efficient methods, have a look at *bulk loading* strategies for R*-trees, such as sort-tile-recursive. It won't satisfy your "only" requirement above, but it will yield well balanced, non-overlapping rectangles.

K-means is obviously not appropriate for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

With only 1000 points I would do the following:

1) Work out the difference between all pairs of points. If the distance of a pair is less than R, they need to go in the same bounding rectangle, so use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure to record this.

2) For each subset that comes out of your Disjoint set data structure, work out the min and max co-ordinates of the points in it and use this to create a bounding box for the points in this subset.

If you have more points or are worried about efficiency, you will want to make stage (1) more efficient. One easy way would be to go through the points in order of x co-ordinate, keeping only points at most R to the left of the most recent point seen, and using a balanced tree structure to find from these the points at most R above or below the most recent point seen, before calculating the distance to the most recent point seen. One step up from this would be to create a spatial data structure to get yet more efficiency in finding pairs with distance R of each other.

Note that for some inputs you will get just one huge bounding box because you have long chains of points, and for some other inputs you will get bounding boxes inside bounding boxes, for instance if your points are in concentric circles.